# SQL - Query using XML Path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT     ara.req_id
FROM        tbl_ara ara
WHERE       id in (
                        SELECT STUFF((
                        SELECT ',' + cast(id as varchar(8000))
                        FROM contact
                        WHERE ct_id = 2
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, ''))
```

So, theres is table with name `contact` that I want to get all the `ids` when they are type of `2`. Then I am creating a list with Stuff.
Then I want to use another table and get all the records that their `id` is on that list.
You can see the logic in the query.
The problem is that SQL doesn't recognise it as list and I get the following error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Conversion failed when converting
>   the nvarchar value
>   '6019,49111,49112'
>   to data type int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STUFF` in your case returns character data. From the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

> Returns character data if character_expression is one of the supported character data types. Returns binary data if character_expression is one of the supported binary data types.

So you do not get a list of IDs but rather a string containing numbers and commas.

Is there a reason for not using the IDs directly?

```
SELECT 
    [ara].[req_id]
FROM [tbl_ara] [ara]
WHERE [id] IN
             (
              SELECT 
                  [id]
              FROM [contact]
              WHERE [ct_id] = 2
             )
```

EDIT: Of course the `JOIN` solution by @gofr1 is a pretty good option, too.

Comment: Yes there is a reason. Its been a while since the last time I used SQL :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is JOIN:

```
SELECT ara.req_id
FROM tbl_ara ara
INNER JOIN contact c
    ON ara.id = c.id
WHERE c.ct_id = 2
```

If you want to run using `STUFF` then you should use dynamic SQL. At first prepare statement, then execute it:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max), @inpart nvarchar(max)

SELECT @inpart = STUFF((
                    SELECT ',' + cast(id as varchar(8000))
                    FROM contact
                    WHERE ct_id = 2
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')


SELECT @sql = '
SELECT     ara.req_id
FROM        tbl_ara ara
WHERE       id in (' + @inpart+ ')'


PRINT @sql

--EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

`PRINT` would get you this:

```
SELECT     ara.req_id
FROM        tbl_ara ara
WHERE       id in (6019,49111,49112)
```

Uncomment `EXEC sp_executesql @sql` to execute query.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this :

```
SELECT  ara.req_id
FROM    tbl_ara As ara
WHERE   Exists( Select  1
                From    contact As c
                Where   c.ct_id = 2
                        And c.id = ara.id
              )
```

As exists clause only check the existence of single match and return that row when match found.