# issues with the in statement using a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

Issues with this statement

```
    select * from table 
        where ID in (case when table1.changes = 40 THEN 
        select top 1 STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CAST(ID as varchar) FROM Tabl1
                WHERE UserID = 121   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
                    FROM Tabl1 where UserID = 121
else 
id
end
        )
```

Using above, getting an error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '167,196,107,108,169,111,115,16,162' to data type int.

Comment: seems to address a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140999/sql-query-using-xml-path

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the integer IDs into a delimited string? You don't need `STUFF( ... FOR XML)` here, you can easily join on the ID column and filter your second table on the UserID. See my answer for the simplified query.

Comment: From the comments in the answer, we appear to actually have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) here, or the OP has given us but a small part of the real problem. They are now making referencing to the `CASE` not working, however, there is not such expression in their question.

Comment: Your question is being down voted because you are responding to answers with requirements you didn't post in your question. Please update your question to show us what you are actually trying to do and why you think you need to use a `CASE` statement.

Comment: That `CASE` expression makes no sense. That SQL would never return that error. It would generate the error `Incorrect syntax near SELECT`. `WHEN SELECT` isn't valid syntax. Stop drip feeding us and give us the **real** SQL and the **real** problem.

Comment: Where does `table1` come from?

Comment: `...else id end` Which table is this `id` column supposed to belong to? Your SQL syntax is  ambiguous (and also very incorrect).

Comment: I've updated my answer, and you STILL don't need `STUFF(... FOR XML)` or a `CASE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is telling you the problem. You're trying to pass a delimited **`varchar`** to an `int` column.

You probably more want this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTabLe YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.OtherTable OT
              WHERE OT.UserID = 121
                AND OT.ID = YT.ID);
```

I personally prefer `(NOT) EXISTS` instead of `(NOT) IN`, mainly because `NOT EXISTS` handles `NULL` values gracefully, where as `NOT IN` does not.

*Edit: based on the latest edit, however, it is a guess, as the new edit has a malformed query:*

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTabLe YT
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.OtherTable OT
              WHERE OT.UserID = 121
                AND OT.ID = YT.ID)
  AND  YT.changes = 40)     --Changes was prefiexed with table1, which doesn't exist in your sample query.
   OR NOT(YT.changes = 40); --I've therefore assumed it was meant to be your table
```

Comment: but it seems you can't use case inside the exists

Comment: *"but it seems you can't use case inside the exist"* yes you can; its implementation is no different to any other query. If your attempt failed, it's because you implemented it incorrectly. There is no `CASE` expression in your sample query though, so I don't know what your attempt was. But putting a `CASE` in the `WHERE` of a query is a bad idea; it'll cause the query to be non-SARGable. Use proper boolean logic.

Comment: I Missed that section, I Updated my question

Comment: Which contains SQL that won't replicate the error, @TreeNode .

Answer (score 1):

[`In`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) takes either a subquery or a list of expressions. You were trying to build a list of expression on-the-fly and that would require using `in` with *dynamic SQL*. The correct syntax for using a subquery is:

```
select * from table
    where ID in ( select ID FROM Tabl1 WHERE UserID = 121 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating things. This is a simple `INNER JOIN` solution. You don't need a `CASE` statement, just an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN Tabl1 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE (t2.changes = 40 AND t2.UserID = 121) 
    OR t2.changes <> 40
```

Comment: can't use join, it has its own case statements within it

Comment: Your question makes no mention of using a `CASE` statement.